# Prisma data modeling has many and belongs to

Tags: graphql, prisma, plumatic-schema

I have a prisma data model that consists of a root Category and a Subcategory.  A Category has many Subcategories and a Subcategory belongs to one Category.  My model looks like this:

```
  type Category {
    id: ID! @unique
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
    name: String!
    subCategories: [SubCategory!]! @relation(name: "Subcategories")
  }

  type SubCategory {
    id: ID! @unique
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
    name: String!
    category: Category! @relation(name: "ParentCategory")

    cards: [Card!]! @relation(name: "SubCategoryCards") #Category @relation(name: "CardCategory")
  }
```

Now when i go to create a new subcategory and via

```
mutation {
    createSubCategory(data:{
        name:"This is a test"
        category:{
            connect:{
                id:"cjp4tyy8z01a6093756xxb04i"
            }
        }
    }){
        id
        category{
            name
            id
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to work fine.  Below I query for the subcategories and their parent Category and I get the results that I expect.

```
{
    subCategories{
        id
        name
        category{
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

However, when i try to query a category, and get all of it's sub categories I'm getting an empty array:

```
{
    categories{
        id
        name
        subCategories{
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

How can I query all categories and get their sub categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MYSQL-knul/#the-@relation-directive), the `@relation` directive is used to specify **both ends of a relation**.

Let's take the following datamodel:

```
type User {
  postsWritten: [Post!]!
  postsLiked: [Post!]!
}

type Post {
  author: User!
  likes: [User!]!
}
```

Here, we have an ambiguous relation between Post and User. Prisma needs to know which User field (`postsWritten`? `postsLiked`?) to link to which Post field (`author`? `likes`?)

To resolve this, we use the `@relation` with a name used in **both ends of the relation**.

This would make the datamodel look like this:

```
type User {
  postsWritten: [Post!]! @relation(name: "AuthorPosts")
  postsLiked: [Post!]! @relation(name: "UserLikes")
}

type Post {
  author: User! @relation(name: "AuthorPosts")
  likes: [User!]! @relation(name: "UserLikes")
}
```

Because we used **the same name** for the `postsWritten` and `author` fields, Prisma is now able to link these two in the database. Same for `postsLiked` and `likes`.

In conclusion, the problem with your datamodel is that you used **different names** in your relation. This confuses Prisma which think those are different relations. Which explains why you can query one way but not another.

Comment: For Prisma 2.0: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema/relations/